# Can't view cached files under Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, caching, google-chrome-devtools

I want to use the cache for local storage of large data files and refresh them with cache busting as described [here](https://www.codebyamir.com/blog/a-web-developers-guide-to-browser-caching) but I can't figure out how to view the cache.

chrome://flags works

chrome://view-http-cache/ doesn't load

chrome://cache/ doesn't load

They respond with "This site can’t be reached"

Visiting a page shows nothing through devtools under Cache -> Cache storage or Application Cache. All the files accessed on the page show a status of 200 where I would have expected 304 for static files. I am using node.js express on the server.

Under devtools on the Network page "Disable cache" is not checked.

How do I view the cache for a particular page?

Comment: In Windows you can use [ChromeCacheView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cache_view.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like `chrome://cache` and `chrome://view-http-cache` were removed a while ago, see https://superuser.com/a/1319699/352120.

The **Size** column of the Network panel tells you when a resource was served from disk cache or memory cache.

[image: Size column in Network panel]

FYI, the **Cache Storage** section of the Application panel refers to the Service Worker cache, not the HTTP cache.